# Copying an array into an array of arrays then writing to file

Tags: c, arrays, file

I am attempting to store an array in an array of arrays, and then writing the result to a file. The issue I am experiencing is that nothing is being written to the file. The following code is a reproducible example of the issue I am experiencing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\whoeveryouare\\blahblah\\yourfile.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot open file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    float** deltas;
    deltas = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float*));
    deltas[0] = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
    float delta[4] = { 1.1F, 2.2F, 3.3F, 4.4F };
    memcpy(&deltas[0], &delta, sizeof(delta));

    if (deltas[0] != NULL) {
        fwrite(deltas[0], sizeof(float), sizeof(deltas[0]), fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

No errors or warnings occur and the file is being opened properly. However, when checking the contexts of the text file, nothing has been written. I constructed this code from previous stack exchange posts, so I am not sure where the flaw lies.

Comment: `sizeof(delta)` is not doing what you expect....

Comment: `deltas[0] = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));` allocates space for 1 float - probably not what you want

Comment: Not sure why you allocate space for pointers if you actually want to store floats. It would make sense to allocate space for pointers which you then let point to some memory which you allocated specifically for each pointer. You do something like that with `deltas[0]` but not for the others.

Comment: Why all the dynamic allocation if you just want to write to a file?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. As you can probably gander, not experienced in C. I "Frankensteined" code together to attempt to do this.

Comment: And there is no `array of array` in the code

Comment: Maybe you should describe what you want to do in more details.

Comment: I wish to construct an array in which its contents are arrays. Then I wish to access specific elements in this array of arrays and write them to a file.

Comment: `float deltas[1][4];` should do

Comment: Re "*I wish to construct an array in which its contents are arrays*", Why? What do you plan in putting in them? Right now, you just have one array of  elements. What's the other dimension for?

Comment: @ikegami Well using my inexperienced logic, I am wanting to save some information after freeing up memory from a struct which has an array as one of its members. This is what motivated my question.

Comment: @4386427 removing memory allocation and replacing `float** deltas` with `float deltas[1][4]` produced this bizarre output in the file : `吞?吞@33S@吞孈FKw2      €?@    ?f  f  P@ @D`

Comment: Let me ask the question differently: How many subarrays do you want? What do you want the first subarray to contain? What do you want the second subarray to contain?

Comment: Don't use `[1]`. It makes no sense to have an array with one element. /// Are you trying to read the file with a text editor? But you didn't even try to write some decimal representations of the numbers.

Comment: The amount of subarrays will vary depending on the user. The program I am modifying reads and loads models with specific information to each model. One specific piece of information is an array of "deltas" that is unique to each model. So the first subarray will contain the array of deltas to the first model, second to the second model, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206599/discussion-between-hkj447-and-ikegami).